# Приостановить приложение на несколько секунд - Java

Tags: java, android, sleep

Здравствуйте. В приложении после нажатии на кнопку - кнопки должны пропадать, а приложение останавливаться на 5 сек. Так вот, у меня почему-то при нажатии кнопки не убираются, а сразу идёт в сон приложение. В чём ошибка?

```
case R.id.no:

                    yes.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    no.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);

                    compare = true;

                    if (compare == MainActivity.value.get(random)) {
                        iscore++;
                        score.setText(Integer.toString(iscore));
                        sp.play(soundIdRight, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                        red2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                        try {
                            SECONDS.sleep(4);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        iscore2++;
                        score2.setText(Integer.toString(iscore2));
                        sp.play(soundIdWrong, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                        red.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                        try {
                            SECONDS.sleep(4);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте `view.GONE`

Comment: Потому что sleep срабатывает раньше чем перерисовка. А т.к. вы блокируете главный поток, то она происходит уже после сна. Функция invalidate у View, позволяет "сказать" системе, что данный элемент управления следует перерисовать. А вообще не очень хорошо так тормозить весь UI-поток. Лучше воспользоваться таймерами ил чем-то в этом роде

Comment: Можно пример как лучше сделать или ссылку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего в ui потоке не должно быть никаких sleep'ов и прочих блокировок, т.к. андроид может показать диалог, что приложение не отвечает, и любезно предложить закрыть его, что для пользователя выглядит не очень.

Не знаю что именно вы имеете ввиду под "остановкой приложения", но если вам надо запретить нажатие на кнопки, то просто сделайте их неактивными на время, надо остановить проигрывание мелодии, то поставьте на паузу и т.п.

Вот небольшой пример

```
//отключаем кнопку
buttonView.setEnabled(false);
//через 5 секунд включаем
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        buttonView.setEnabled(true);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Я вот и пытаюсь понять как мне на время сделать их неактивными. Я не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь всё работает.